# Show that two subspaces are equal with a given assumption

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

Let $A,B,C$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Assume $A\cap B=A\cap C$, $A+B=A+C$ and $B\subseteq C$. Show that $B=C$.

We have that
$$\dim (A\cap B)+\dim(A+B)=\dim A+\dim B$$
$$\dim (A\cap C)+\dim(A+C)=\dim A+\dim C$$
subtracting the first from second, we get through the assumption that $\dim B=\dim C$. Since $B\subseteq C$, we conclude that $\dim B=\dim C$ implies $B=C$. I know well that the conclusion is not really correct. I am unsure how to fix this. There is another way I would like to prove it by contradition. I would pick an $y\in B$ but $y\notin C$ and then conclude that $y\in C$. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your second argument, suppose there exists a $y \in B$ but $y \notin C$. 
If $y \in A$, then $y \in A \cap B$ but $y \notin A\cap C$, so $A \cap B \neq A \cap C$, contradiction. Therefore, $y \notin A$. But then $y \notin A+C$, contradicting the fact that  $y \in A+B$ and $A+B = A+C$. Therefore $y \in C$ and we are done.